# Need help in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Will this code block $ % # or ( as I type?

```
var digitsOnly = /[0-9]/g;
var emailOnly = /[a-zA-Z0-9_.@-]/g;
var alphaOnly = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
var dateOnly = /[0-9\/]/g;

function restrictKeys(myfield, e, restrictionType) {

    if (!e) var e = window.event
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);

    // if they pressed esc... remove focus from field...
    if (code==27) { this.blur(); return false; }

    // ignore if they are press other keys
    // strange because code: 39 is the down key AND ' key...
    // and DEL also equals .
    if (!e.ctrlKey && code!=9 && code!=8 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && (code!=39 || (code==39 && character=="'")) && code!=40) {
        if (character.match(restrictionType)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you should just try it.

Comment: Your email expression needs some work

Comment: I've tried but this code isn't blocking the characters that I mentioned.

Comment: Try echoing the code you're getting with each key. Use an alert()

Comment: @austinbv I know it would be something like this /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/ (though it's not the best one) but it's not working like match the pattern as I type... Thanks.

Comment: The problem of this code is it can restrict characters as I type but can't match the pattern at the same time :(

Comment: @Alfabravo Thanks for help. Any alternative so that it will not take those input other than using alert(). I'd really be thankful.

Comment: I meant to check the codes while developing: maybe your codes are wrong. Maybe it's not just ctrl+something but shift+something... I encourage you to try and test using the most basic JS debug: alerts

Comment: Also, I don't know why the g ending the regexp. v.gr: A number will match /^[\d]+$/

Answer (score 2):

> Will this code block $ % # or ( as I
>   type?

No. Detecting keys pressed is futile, users can paste or drag text into form controls so the key codes don't match the text being entered (or not fire a key event at all). Also, you only care about the value **when the form is submitted**, whatever value it has in the meantime is irrelevant to you.

Validate form control content on submit, restricting keyboard entry by any means is very, very annoying for users and easily bypassed.